# Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "cryptoApi" has not been added to the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to this concept of redux toolkit and I am facing this issue where I can see the data in console but I am contantly getting this error due to which the web app is crashing .
"Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "cryptoApi" has not been added to the store.
You must add the middleware for RTK-Query to function correctly!"
This is my store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { cryptoApi } from "../services/cryptoApi";

export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer,
    },
})
```

This is my cryptoApi.js

```
import { BehanceSquareOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import {createApi ,fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
  const cryptoApiHeaders={
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'blabla',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
  const baseUrl = 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com';

  const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders });
  export const cryptoApi =createApi({
    reducerPath:'cryptoApi',
    baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
    endpoints:(builder) =>({
        getCryptos:builder.query({
            query:()=> createRequest('/coins')
        })
    })
  })

  export const {
    useGetCryptosQuery 
  } = cryptoApi;
```

and my index.js

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Router>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
  </Router>
  
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

It is difficult to guage exact reason behind this because I believe I am calling things properly .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forget to add the API in the middleware

```js
export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cryptoApi.middleware),

})
```

here is link https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/redux-integration#middleware

Comment: yeah ,your suggestion seems to be right .i am trying to follow this from youtube to learn some redux tookit but this project doesn't have the middleware you mentioned .
https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_cryptoverse

Comment: One Tip: just open the docs in another tab and just search the term where you could not find the answer.

Comment: yup .it works like charm .check your linkedin.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com';

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders });
export const cryptoApi = createApi({
    reducerPath:'cryptoApi',
    baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
    endpoints:(builder) =>({
        getCryptos:builder.query({
            query:()=> createRequest('/coins')
        })
    })
})
```

Here add `/` to the url: `https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/`